# Remove space between rectangles canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rectangles

I created an array of rectangles, with each having 100 wide more than the previous.

```
var pos = new Vector2(0, 0);

for(var i=0;i<numRects;i++) {
    rects[i] = new Rectangle(new Vector2(pos.X, 0), sizeRect, sizeRect);
    pos.X += sizeRect;
}
```

But the print on the screen there is a small spacing between them.

```
for(var i=0;i<numRects;i++) {
    Game.drawRect("blue", rects[i].pos, rects[i].width, rects[i].height);
}
```

Full source code: https://jsfiddle.net/gtspina/cg8t9x1w/5/

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I just added 1 to the width of the rectangles and it looked nice, but I don't think thats a reliable fix... Just throwing that out there.

Comment: Thanks, but it should work with current measures.

Comment: The reason you're seeing this is because you change the `context`'s scale, which resizes your elements and make their borders blurry because of anti-aliasing. I wasn't able to deactivate anti-aliasing but removing the code that sets the scale fixed the problem. Not posting as answer because this is more of a workaround and there may be better solutions.

Comment: Scaling will produce white lines between rects just as lleaff said, If I were you just create the rects and have a `widthScale` and `heightScale` which you use to multiple the positions and size so you do your own scaling which will remove the white lines

Comment: It's not `scale()`in itself which does produce these artifacts, but rather because you are drawing on floating points (e.g, in the fiddle the scale is `X:0.3645680819912152, Y: 0.36328125` for me, so when it will try to draw in pos 200,200, it will actually try to draw at position `72.91361639824304,72.65625`. Obviously, it can't draw semi-pixels, so it will create some artifacts to give the impression of the semi-pixels. You can't do nothing, apart from checking that you always do draw on rounded pixel location, either by drawing first on a scale(MAth.ceil(s),Math.ceil(s)) canvas,...

Comment: ...then drawImage this canvas at wanted scale, or by completely rethinking your rescale functions to avoid it falls into the anti-aliasing nightmare. (Here your ratio is incorrect, and your code is really too complicated for what you want, so I'd go with the second option in your position).